# Rails and Devise: Can't use admin and user views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I generated two models: Admin and User for my application, and I also generated views for each of them:

`rails generate devise user`

`rails generate devise admin`

`rails g devise:views admin`

`rails g devise:views user`

and added the next line in the `devise.rb` file:

`config.scoped_views = true`

I want to use different pages for user login and admin login, but instead the default devise login page is being called.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to create only `devise user` and can override views once.

After that you have to create a different model `Role` to determine whether the user is `admin`, `editor`, `moderator` or `anything` else.

If you dont want Another model then you can use several gems in rails.

- Rollify gem
- Cancan gem

In the Above scenario, it will make devise complicated.

**Edited:**

To accomplish above scenario

You need to use devise_group

You need to create another model `everyone`

```
rails g devise Everyone
```

Now you need to define it in your `Application Controller`

```
devise_group :everyone, contains: [:user, :admin]
```

This might help!!!

Comment: "Replace MODEL with the class name used for the application’s users (it’s frequently User but could also be Admin). This will create a model (if one does not exist) and configure it with the default Devise modules. The generator also configures your config/routes.rb file to point to the Devise controller... " @Pravesh Khatri please check that: Devise documentation  https://github.com/plataformatec/devise

Comment: You can use it as per your requirement. Well i have just edited. Thanks.

Comment: @Pradesh Khatri, the truth is that I was looking to solve my issue. I like the solution that devise provides, but thank you very much for your help.

Comment: @PraveshKhatri It sounds like a good idea but actually there's no enough doc about this feature. I don't understand whats the main advantage of using `devise_group`. I have created a `Member` model with `rails g devise member` then I created `Organizer` & `Sponsor` models with `rails g model [Organizer, Sponsor]` this last two inherit from Member but what else do I need to do to be able create a member but at the same time create the other attributes for an organizer or sponsor respectively. I don't see the real advantage for `devise_group` and I can't find a good documentation about it.

Comment: @PraveshKhatri I've seen your answers in different questions talking about `devise_group` so, can you write like a post or something like that to explain the proper usage for `devise_group` please? It will come in handy for many other too. I really appreciate your help, thanks in advance.

Comment: @AlexVentura : i am really glad, that my answer helped you. I will surely post a blog in that. Thank you alex

Comment: @PraveshKhatri C'mon your very welcome! I really will appreciate your help with my problem or I don't know how to design the correct logic for my app for different models to be able to log in and sign up in different forms and with different attributes. It does not matter if the routes are different but also I'd like to know if it is possible to log in for all the models in the same route (it is not a must just for knowledge). Thank you a lot!